# Are there any small scale, durable document/object databases?

Tags: .net, document-database

I have a few .Net projects that would benefit from using a document/object database opposed to a relational one.  I think that [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) would be a good choice, but we're not sure how much the cost is.  I'd love to use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) but it's design isn't for small scale, single server applications.

Are there other options out there that I just haven't run across for small scale applications?

---

EDIT: So is this a space that doesn't have a good solution, yet?  Are there no small scale & durable document databases?  Would my best choice be to use MongoDB and set the --syncdelay option set to 1?

Comment: I ran into this http://java-source.net/open-source/database-engines the other day (I was looking for db4o alternatives :-). It provided me with a good 'fan' in my searching. There truly are a number of viable solutions and different approaches. A number of the DBs listed there provide commercial licenses, for cost. Also, despite the name, some of them offer .NET versions and/or have .NET clones.

Comment: Thanks pst. That's a good link. I hadn't run into that list before.

Comment: Not released yet, so I won't post as an answer - but Raven DB may be interesting: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/03/23/unveiling-raven-db.aspx

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I've seen the posts about it and it does sound like it might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [RavenDB](http://github.com/ravendb/ravendb) looks to fit what I'm looking for.  I played around with the source and gave it a spin.  It's a mix of CouchDB and MongoDB.  The main difference is that it uses the ESE engine built into Windows which provides crash recovery, which is mainly what I'm looking for.  According to [Ayende's Blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/) there's still much more to be done before it's released, but it's fun to follow along from GutHub.

Answer (score 1):

[BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) is pretty good.

Comment: The pricing is a bit high for us at $900/processor.

Comment: If you're not releasing the software (e.g. it's only on the server), or you're releasing the software as open source, then you can use the Open Source license.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware.  DB4O is under GPL, but we're looking to sell the software.

Comment: A pretty good hash store -- I wouldn't really consider it object-based.

Answer (score 1):

if, it's really very small scale, just serialize/deserialize it yourself :) or create a document based structure in an embedded relational database like SqLite...